# Is there a way to tell FxCop that a type is supposed to be immutable?

Tags: c#, fxcop

I have a type which contains a collection of constant data. The constants are defined by a standard which is defined outside of my program. The type looks like this:

```
public class IAmImmutable
{
    public IAmImmutable(string member1, string member2)
    {
        this.Member1 = member1;
        this.Member2 = member2;
    }

    public string Member1 { get; private set; }

    public string Member2 { get; private set; }

    public static readonly Instance1 = new IAmImmutable("abc", "def");
    public static readonly Instance2 = new IAmImmutable("example", "data");
    public static readonly Instance3 = new IAmImmutable("for", "stackoverflow");
    public static readonly Instance4 = new IAmImmutable("these are", "constant fields");
    public static readonly Instance5 = new IAmImmutable("42", "1729");
    /* ... */
    public static readonly Instance1000 = new IAmImmutable("HUNGRY EVIL", "ZOMBIES");
}
```

This results in thousands of `CA2104:DoNotDeclareReadOnlyMutableReferenceTypes` detections from FxCop. The notes in this detection indicate that one should suppress the detection if the indicated type is immutable, which it is in this case. However, I don't want to have thousands and thousands of suppressions if I can avoid doing that.

Is it possible to mark this type as immutable and therefore prevent this detection from occuring?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2006/04/04/faq-how-do-i-indicate-to-donotdeclarereadonlymutablereferencetypes-that-a-type-is-immutable-david-kean.aspx

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274412/immutable-readonly-reference-types-fxcop-violation-do-not-declare-read-only-m

Comment: @Peter: That question is about an immutable type which contains internal mutable members. This type has no internal mutable members. If there was a `StringBuilder` inside that would be an entirely different question.

Answer (score 2):

See an article explaining how to do this on [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2006/04/04/faq-how-do-i-indicate-to-donotdeclarereadonlymutablereferencetypes-that-a-type-is-immutable-david-kean.aspx).

It appears that FxCop looks for a text file called `ImmutableTypes.txt` for types that it should consider "immutable".

For what it's worth, your class IS mutable from within, even though you don't explicitly mutate it.  One change that *would* make it immutable is to change the properties from auto-implemented to get-only properties backed by readonly fields:

```
public IAmImmutable(string member1, string member2)
{
    this._Member1 = member1;
    this._Member2 = member2;
}

private readonly string _Member1;
private readonly string _Member2;

public string Member1 { get {return _Member1;} }
public string Member2 { get {return _Member2;} }
```

(Whether FxCop recognizes this as an "immutable" class is another question)

Note that this *only* works because `string` is immutable.  If it were changed to a mutable type (like `List` or an `Array`), then the *reference* would be readonly but the *contents* could be modified, hence making the class itself mutable.

Comment: @D Stanley: Not really. Adding readonly only enforces anything at compile time for that class; if one was to add a mutating member to the class in the future they could just add that member and remove `readonly`. That would not be a breaking change. Of course, that could subtly break code expecting "free threading" but the framework would not complain.

Comment: The fact that a field is of a mutable reference type does not imply that the class is mutable, if there is no execution path via which the information encapsulated by the field could actually change.  As a simple example, if the constructor of an object creates an array of five integers, fills in those values, and then stores a reference in a private field, and if it never exposes that array to anything that could mutate it, I would consider the class to be immutable (at least as far as the array is concerned).  Further, knowing that the *identity* of the thing referred to by a field is...

Comment: ...constant is often useful even (*especially*) in cases where the content might change.  Suppose, for example, a class uses an `int[]` to encapsulate some information and has a method that returns a `ReadOnlyCollection<int>` that wraps it.  If the `int[]` variable is readonly, then the wrapper will represent a live view of the collection; if code that wants to change a value always makes a copy, changes the copy, and makes the field point to the new copy, the wrapper will represent a snapshot.  If the code uses the `int[]` the way list does, the wrapper may cease to be meaningful...

Comment: ...if the collection is changed.  It's too bad neither .NET nor Java allows a declaration to specify whether a field encapsulates mutable state that might change, "mutable state" that won't be changed by code to which a reference is exposed, identity but not mutable state, identity and mutable state, or neither identity nor mutable state.  Knowing what a field is supposed to encapsulate is very different from knowing its type.

Comment: @BillyONeal if you don't have an FxCop project file you can try putting it in the FxCop installation folder (likely `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio {X}\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\ImmutableTypes.txt`)

Comment: @D Stanley: That's not acceptable for this case unfortunately (I can't force the whole team to do that)